# How can I restore the man page for ls (/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz)?

Tags: linux, ls, man

I was messing around with the man page files whereupon I accidentally deleted `ls.1.gz`, which describes the man page for `ls`.

Is there somewhere where I can download a copy of this file which I can plonk back into /usr/share/man/man1? Or is there any other way I could recover this file?

To add: this is on an Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

There may be an easier way, but I assume reinstalling the package `ls` belongs to would do the job.

You can `which ls` to find the path to `ls`
Then `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls` (assuming that is your path to `ls`)
Followed by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename`

Comment: On my current Linux Mint 21.3 system, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls` gives no results

Answer (score 1):

Found the [Ubuntu Manpage Repository](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/) which contained the [manpage for ls](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ls.1.html) in addition to many others, including versions for different versions of Ubuntu too.